# What are "Active Users" defined as in Trigger.IO

Tags: trigger.io

We just had an update go live in the iOS app store and see "x" number of users as "active" within Trigger.IO's toolkit. However, iTunes Connect shows that we have "5x" updates.

Why is there a disparity between those numbers? We reloaded immediately after pushing to the store. Has the update not applied to some of these users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active users should be the number of users who have requested a reload update in the last week, reload updates are requested when your app is loaded, and also when the app goes into the background on the device.

There are a couple of things that could be happening here:

- We update the number of active users periodically, you may need to just wait a little while for the number to update
- Users who have not yet opened your application won't appear as active users, iTunes will probably count everyone who has downloaded/updated your app, but they won't appear in the toolkit until they actually run the app (and have internet access for the update check to go through when they do).

Taking that into account let us know if the numbers still don't make sense and we can look into it just in case there is a problem on our end.

Comment: Perfect, that's actually really helpful for determining a more exact figure of usage then. Thanks